# SearchView in ActionBar not full width

Tags: android

I implemented a searchView in Actionbar

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search_item));
    searchView.setQueryHint("hint ...");
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

SearchView is not full width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put it in your code :

```
searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```